# how to cast class to ((Int,String) -> Unit ) in kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

In Kotlin I can implement this Invokable `((Int,String) -> Unit )` in class `(Int,String) -> Unit` 
without write interface but I need cast object to this Invokable  type from another class .

[image]

[image]

Comment: In your snippet you're implementing an `OnClickListener` anonymously already. There's no need for you to implement an Invokeable interface. You can have a function called `foo` and do `context.foo(...)` where you have that cast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the return value in the type of the function you're casting to. You should probably do a safe cast so you can provide a proper error message for easier debugging if it comes to it.

```
(context as? (Int, MenuItem) -> Unit)?.invoke(position - 1, menuItem) 
    ?: error("Failed to pass Activity with appropriate invoke function")
```

Just my opinion, but I think for code clarity, interfaces are a better choice than implementing function types.

Comment: thank you for your answer 
please Can you explain why you prefer the interface to this type of implement

Comment: Mainly because your function can have a meaningful name. But also you could implement multiple interfaces with functions having different names that otherwise would have the same signature. When you do it without an interface, you’re stuck with only one allowable implementation.

Answer (score -1):

Its Higher-order functions or Function as parameter and for casting use keyword "is" for check instance and "as" for direct casting

Your adapter looks like this:

```
CommonListAdapter(val mList: MutableList<Any>,
                  val onClick: (item: Any) -> Unit) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>()
```

And now your view

```
adapter = CommonListAdapter(arrayListOf()) {
            val bundle = Bundle()
            if (it is StateItem) {
                bundle.putParcelable(StateItem::class.simpleName, it)
            } else if (it is LgaItem) {
                bundle.putParcelable(LgaItem::class.simpleName, it)
            } 
            val intent = Intent().putExtras(bundle)
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent)
            finish()
}
binding.recyclerView.adapter = adapter
```

Use below links for more details.

[Higher Order Functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#higher-order-functions)
[Type Casting](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/typecasts.html)